# Configuring mitmproxy in OSX High Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm struggling configuring mitmproxy on OSX (10.13.1).
pfctl command always returns `syntax error` when trying to set forwarding rules.
I tried `rdr on en2 inet proto tcp to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr on en2 inet proto tcp to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080`
from the official guide as well as similar commands from other resources, but with the same error.
I also get `No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled` even though the firewall is enabled.
Is it some specifics related to the OS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly, a newline character is actually required at the end of the config file, and not only will `pfctl` fail without it, but it also will only tell you "syntax error". (That's what the issue was for me at least.)

Apparently this has been causing grief [since at least 2010](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/pf-syntax-error.11511/#post-69031).